How to gracefully handle missing user data in React without revealing backend issues?
I’m building a microservices-based application and in the front-end I'm using React and TypeScript. In one of the services, I fetch post data to display to users. Each post has a user field containing details about the user who created the post. However, if the user service is down, the user field in the response is null.
Here’s an example of the response when the user service is unavailable:
{
  "id": 1,
  "content": "Sample post content",
  "user": null
}

In such cases, I want to display the post without revealing to the user that there’s an issue (like the user service being down). For example, I might display something like "Anonymous" in place of the user’s name. However, I want to avoid explicitly using if-else or ternary operations to handle the null value.
I’ve Tried Using optional chaining, but it still requires me to provide fallback logic like user?.name || "Anonymous" also I’ve Tried Wrapping the logic in a function, but it feels repetitive across components.
What’s the best way to cleanly handle such scenarios in React, ensuring maintainability and avoiding repetitive conditional logic throughout the codebase?

Create a component for your user display logic and use that wherever you display the username.

How about defining a function to fetch your user to always resolve to a User?
Something like:
interface User {
  name: string
}

export const fetchUser = async (): Promise<User> => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('api.com/user')
    return (await reponse.json()) as User;
  } catch (error) {
    return { name: 'Anonymous' }
  }
}

Keep in mind that request failures can still be visible in the network tab of the developer console.
